# GIMP tries to access a scanner each time GIMP gets started. How can I disable this?

Tags: gimp, scanner

Each time I start GIMP, GIMP is invoking a command to my EPSON Photoscanner. How can I disable this behavior? As the scanner isn't connected (most of the time), I always get a message that sending a command to the scanner failed. The program invoked is iscan, the standard program for using the Epson Photoscanner.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. When I start Gimp from the command-line, I get the message underneath:

bernard@Sable:~$ gimp
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
`menu_proxy_module_load': /usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/iscan: undefined symbol: menu_proxy_module_load

(iscan:3947): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to load type module: (null)

So at installation of the scanner a plug-in for Gimp was automatically created? I removed the link and now Gimp is starting up without accessing the scanner.